# Switching between View Controllers via action method inside current view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

My situation is that I have a Primary View Controller (`UIViewController` in `PrimaryViewController.h .m`) that contains a `UIButton`. When pressed, a second View Controller (`UINavigationController`) is displayed, the general idea is to press a "settings" button and for a navigation view to pop up and allow the user to amend their settings.

I have been able to do this, but I am not entirely confident with my method. Inside the Primary View Controller I have added a Navigation Controller and linked it as an outlet inside the Primary controller. Then when the button is pressed, the function, `showSettings` is called:

```
- (IBAction)showSettings {
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Similarly a hideSettings is called to close. Whilst this does work, I'm not sure I've done this in the best or correct way. I did previously try to create the Navigation Controller in the `MainWindow.xib` and link it with the App Delegate, however I ran into a problem where I needed to call/display this controller in the `PrimaryViewController.m` implementation file and couldn't work out how to do this (i.e. how to perform `[super addSubview:];` outside the App Delegate class).

I could use what I have now, but would like to know the alternate method to doing this, primarily because I am not happy with the transition animation for Modal View Controllers and would rather use a flip animation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right, instead of using `presentModalViewController` I'm simply  using `addSubview:navigationViewController.view`. This works, but rather strangely the view is placed about 20 pixels below the main window and I can see the view underneath it.

Comment: Had to adjust the frame and set the Layout to "Wants full screen" in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:
1.  Create a separate class file for a navigation controller. Say call it MyNavigateController.  You can add this to your YourAppAppDelegate.
MyNavigateController.h looks like this:

```
@interface MyNavigateController : UIViewController 
{
    UINavigationController *navController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
@end
```

MyNavigateController.m looks like this for the viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[self.view addSubview:self.navController.view];
}
```

For MyNavigateController.xib, use drag a Navigation Controller object and assign it to your PrimaryViewController class.

In your PrimaryViewController class

```
- (IBAction)showSettings {
    ChildViewController *childViewController = [ChildViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ChildViewController" bundle:nil];
//childViewController.ivarsifany = ....  //optionaly assign values to ivars etc.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childViewController
                                         animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `MyNavigateController *childViewController = [MyNavigateController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ChildViewController" bundle:nil];`? and where have you declared `navigationController` for `self.navigationController`?

Comment: No... ChildViewController is the whatever child view controller class that you want to present from PrimaryViewController.  It can be another UIViewController, etc.

self.navigationController resulted from the step that I mentioned above: "For MyNavigateController.xib, use drag a Navigation Controller object and assign it to your PrimaryViewController class."

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is the specific transition animation for `presentModalViewController:`, then you can just change the transition type. There are a few different given transition animations, like this:

```
- (IBAction)showSettings {
    [navigationViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationViewController animated:YES];
}
```

There are more transition styles, such as `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`, `UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve`, and `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`.